# Label as a Custom Button in JavaFX? (By using FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a FXML document containing the visual basis of my JavaFX project and I want to make an own Topbar (where the X, minumum/maximum, etc... is) by using a Pane. But my program will have multiply pages (scenes) and to keep the code clean, I wanted to make the Custom-Topbar as a separate class (an component object kinda). I just don't know how I should implement this class into the FXML basis I use (I am using Scene Builder).

Comment: You could make your main pane a `BorderPane`; add your TopBar to the top portion and load additional scenes within the center. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html

Comment: the component you created is used in `FXML` files like any other component `<TopBar fx: id = "..." />`. if you are using a `scenebuilder` as an external application, you will need to import the jar user control file into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1

If the toolbar is always there you can have a main fxml file with the toolbar and a container.
Then load content from other fxmls and place that content in the container. To switch pages switch the content of the container (and not the scene).

Option 2

Create an fxml file with just the toolbar. Then use the `<fx: include />` tag in your other fxmls to include the toolbar. This is like a "component".

**Edit**: This is how option 2 can work in practice.

Say `toolbar.fxml` is the name of the fxml file containing only the toolbar.

Simply include `<fx:include source="toolbar.fxml"/>` in an other fxml file to incldue the toolbar at that location. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements) for more information.

Comment: In Option 2, how exactly do I include this "component" in FXML? I have a BorderPane as the layout and how do I get the external toolbar component included in the top side of the BorderPane?

Comment: @UpdateDotExe Does my edit answer your question? For the BorderPane, you just include `<fx:include source="toolbar.fxml"/>` in the `<top> </top>` tags